# Avoid repeated items on child collection when using join

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm doing this query on Nhibernate

```
FROM             Entity e
LEFT JOIN FETCH  e.Collection1
LEFT JOIN FETCH  e.Collection2
LEFT JOIN FETCH  e.Collection3
```

Because of the join, I'm getting the same element repeated many times on Collection3. How can I eager load all collections while avoiding repeated items?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `"Transformers.DistinctRootEntity"`:

```
session.QueryOver<Entity>()
   .Fetch(entity => entity.SubEntity).Eager
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
   .List();
```

But It was done it on web server layer (Not SQL Server)

If you want to get only some fields (not entity), you can use Distinct or Group By.

Answer (score 0):

For eager loading using one join then `.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)` will work just fine. See this [blog post](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/using-eager-loading-can-produce.html) for an example (Using eager loading can produce unexpected results).  However as soon as you have two or more joins then `TransformUsing` breaks down.

See this [blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate) from Ayende tilted `Eagerly loading entity associations efficiently with NHibernate`.